# Getting rid of white space after transform

Tags: css, jsx, transform

I'm trying to translate an element such that it always stays on the screen, but it seems that it's leaving some whitespace on the bottom. I can't use position absolute as I want high performance on the animation. I have tried making the width and height 0 and changing the transform-origin property, but nothing has worked so far. [Here](https://tsa-space.netlify.app/) is my website and the relevant code.

JSX:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      let test = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollToTop')[0];
      test.style.transform =
        'translate(calc(100vw - 36px - 10px),' +
        (window.scrollY -
          document.body.scrollHeight +
          window.innerHeight -
          10) +
        'px)';
      console.log(test.style.transform);
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);
```

CSS:

```
.scrollToTop {
  /* opacity: 0; */
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  visibility: none;
  background: var(--blue);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: why not use `position: fixed`? making element to stay on screen is better using this instead of engineering a position for it on a non-fixed position, even performance wise, it'd be better using fixed position

Comment: Like @Damzaky said, `position: fixed` is meant for this scenario—positioned _fixed_ against the container and _always visible_ within the viewport. Performance-wise, continuous listening for `scroll` event might be potentially more noticeable.